# how do we use trained model for test new dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I trained a model to predict tags of stackoverfow questions. But now i want to add a function in the system such that when i provide a question in textbox it should predict tags of that question automatically.

i provide code below. please provide me a solutions of my problem..

```
rm(list = ls())
# for installing the library run following codes
install.packages("readr")
install.packages("caret")
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("RTextTools")

library(readr)
library(caret)
library(tm)
library(RTextTools)

# set file path
setwd("C:/Users/topic modeling/topic modeling")

# read the questions file and tags file
train = read_csv("train.csv")
# selected only top 40000 records for memory constarint
train = train[1:40000,] 

# check the tags
tags = data.frame(table(train$Tag))

names(tags) = c("Tags", "Count")
tags = tags[order(-tags$Count),]
print(head(tags))

# selected only top 15 tags and related data for processing
tags = tags$Tags[1:15]
train =  subset(train, train$Tag %in% tags)
train$TagId = match(train$Tag,tags)
print(nrow(train))

# 90% we took for training
x = round(nrow(train) * 0.9)


# cleaning the data
train$Title = toupper(train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("[<].*[>]", "", as.character(train$Title))
train$Title = gsub("&amp", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("@\\w+", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("http\\w+", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", train$Title)
train$Title = gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", train$Title) 

# create document matrix
matrix <- create_matrix(train["Title"], language="english", weighting=tm::weightTfIdf)
container <- create_container(matrix,train$TagId,trainSize=1:x, testSize=(x+1):nrow(train),virgin=FALSE)

# create maxent model using SVM
maxent_model <- train_models(container,algorithms=c("SVM"))
maxent_results <- classify_models(container,maxent_model)

# test the model on test data
maxenttestData = train[(x+1):nrow(train),]
maxenttestData = data.frame(maxenttestData, maxent_results)
write.csv(maxenttestData, "MAXENT.csv", row.names = FALSE)   
save(maxent_model, file = "maxent.rda")

new = read_csv("new.csv")
newtestdata= new[1:nrow(new),]
#print(newtestdata)
load("maxent.rda")
predict(maxent_model, newdata = newtestdata)
```

this code showing error "Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list""

Comment: Use the `predict` function where you will have to pass the model object and the test data post feature engineering with the same structure you used during training

Comment: can you provide me code example?

Comment: give me some example please

Comment: please provide me the code of my problem

Comment: Since you are using SVM, you can look at this [link](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/e1071/html/predict.svm.html)

Comment: still i  did not found any solution